# Wi-Fi Direct Support on Android Froyo

Tags: android, wifi, android-2.2-froyo

I am a beginner to the Android Platform

I am using the USB Enabled Wi-Fi CHip from Marvell; Marvell is providing support in the HAL Layer to support the Wi-Fi Direct.

Is there any other dependency on the Andoird Source that has to be taken care to support the Wi-FI Direct(I see the Wi-Fi Direct feature to be supported on android 4.0)

Can we port the frameworks and Application from Android ICS on to the Android Froyo.

Please let me know your views and suggestion and concern which i have to for see before Porting the Wi-Fi Direct on the Froyo.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wifi direct is implemented in `driver/chip` and `wpa_supplicant`. So if Marvell provides this for you your only addition to froyo should be modifications to `gui/framework`.